# Sencha Touch 2 Panel w/ Template include Data and an Object

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm wondering if it's possible to include both data and make a new object in a template in Sencha Touch 2?

I have the following code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.VideosDetail', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'videosdetail',

config: {
    title: 'Details',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    tpl: [
        '{content}',
        {
            xtype: 'video',
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            url: '{link}'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

I see `[object Object]` instead of a video object with the link url.

The `{content}` works correctly via a store and such.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, two things you have to remember

1. You cannot use a complicated object inside of the tpl in the manner you just did. In Sencha Touch, adding a "," followed by a "{ . . . }" after the tpl strings implies adding member functions or configurations to your XTemplate. In this case, ST misunderstood your object to be a member function of sorts, and didn't display anything since you didnt call any function.

Example of member functions ::

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<p>Name: {name}</p>',
'<p>Kids: ',
'<tpl for="kids">',
    '<tpl if="this.isGirl(name)">',
        '<p>Girl: {name} - {age}</p>',
    '<tpl else>',
        '<p>Boy: {name} - {age}</p>',
    '</tpl>',
    '<tpl if="this.isBaby(age)">',
        '<p>{name} is a baby!</p>',
    '</tpl>',
'</tpl></p>',
{
    // XTemplate configuration:
    disableFormats: true,
    // member functions:
    isGirl: function(name){
       return name == 'Sara Grace';
    },
    isBaby: function(age){
       return age < 1;
    }
}
);
```

2. If you have a complex tpl object, always try to create a separate XTemplate object instead, that will make your code simple and beautiful (ie easy to read)
3. I have done something similar and added videos to my XTemplate before. But I haven't used the video object. Instead, my tpl that I created looks as follows ::

   [image: Sorry I couldnt paste in the code, but StackOverflow was assuming it was html, and actually showing me the tpl output instead :P]

In my scenario, the url of my video was composed of two parts, vurl1 was something common like "www.youtube.com/watch?" and the vcode1 was the dynamic code that followed.